# Share Text in whatsapp and choosing multiple contact

Tags: android, messaging, whatsapp, android-sharing

Good Day,

I want to implement a sharing in my app, where a simple text will be share in whatsapp by choosing multiple contact and will return to me the number of contact I chose to share with. I tried the code below, but only allows me one contact or a group.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sample");
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, WhatsApp does not support for multiple contacts share. In their [FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012) page, its clearly mentioned the steps to share with a single person, but not multiple.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Any workaround? or if I send via group, is there any chance I can get a response on how many contact in that group?

Comment: Not that I know of, because WhatsApp doesn't provide any APIs for anything else other than sharing to a particular contact or group.